# Getting an xml element value using xpath

Tags: php, xml, for-loop, xpath, google-custom-search

I'm parsing xml results from a google xml search results feed and I'm struggling to get the image value from within a specific `DataObject` element

```
<DataObject type="cse_thumbnail">
    <Attribute name="width" value="395"/>
    <Attribute name="height" value="127"/>
    <Attribute name="src" value="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTZMcIvtnauaF5yVIAcxEsJgj-r78xsi32b18X5tuMamDZIVWNBTXoB-g"/>
</DataObject>
```

This is my current loop

```
foreach ($xml->RES->R as $item) {
   $image = $item->PageMap->DataObject[4]->Attribute[2]['value'];
}
```

The problem I get is the image I'm trying to grab isn't always in the 4th `DataObject`. The xml search results feed can have either just one or several `DataObject elements.`

So i've done a little reading to find that xpath will give me the abbility to target the correct `DataObject` width the attribute of `type` and the value of `cse_thumbnail`, regardless of how many DataOjects exist within a parent element (`<PageMap>`).

This is where I get stuck.

```
foreach ($xml->RES->R as $item) {
          $image = $item->PageMap->xpath('DataObject[@type="cse_thumbnail"]/Attribute[@name="src"]/@value');

}
```

The `$image` variable returns as an Array. I thought it would return the value from the `<Attribute>` where `name="src"`.

`array(1) { [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#14 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["value"]=> string(110) "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTZMcIvtnauaF5yVIAcxEsJgj-r78xsi32b18X5tuMamDZIVWNBTXoB-g" } } }`

Can anyone shed any light on what I am doing wrong

Thanks

Comment: Xpath in SimpleXMLElement is *always* an array. That's just as documented: http://php.net/simplexmlelement.xpath - However sister library DOMDocuement with the DOMXPath object allows you to get string values from the DOM directly: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xPath is correct, you can check it online, for example:
http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath

But the PageMap returns an array, check this thread here for possible solutions:
[PHP Xpath extracting a value for a node with attribute name="author"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012319/php-xpath-extracting-a-value-for-a-node-with-attribute-name-author)

Something like:

```
foreach ($xml->RES->R as $item) {    
   $images = $item->PageMap->xpath('DataObject[@type="cse_thumbnail"]/Attribute[@name="src"]/@value');    
   if (count($images)) {
       $image = (string) $images[0]['value'];    
   }    
}
```